# vector indexing to construct the matrix

Tags: matlab

Define a, b and c to be, respectively, the first, the second, and the third 17 primes.
Use vector indexing to construct the following
ac =[a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, . . .]

I have already constructed vectors a,b and but I dont know how to put them together to get ac,I suppose function horzcat isn`t the right solution but I am not sure.

a =[ 2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    31    37    41    43    47    53    59]

b = [61    67    71    73    79    83    89    97   101   103   107   109   113   127   131   137   139]

c =[149   151   157   163   167   173   179   181   191   193   197   199   211   223   227   229   233]

Comment: hi @joel4! wellcome to stackoverflow! could you include the source code? to get an answer about how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most efficient would be this:

```
ac = reshape([a;b;c],1,[])
```

But since you are explicitly asked to use *vector indexing*, you can either use sanmiyom's solution, or this:

```
ac = zeros(1,length(a)*3);
for n = 1:length(a)
    ac((n-1)*3+1:n*3) = [a(n), b(n), c(n)];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ac = [];
for i = 1:17
    ac = [ac a(i) b(i) c(i)];
end
```